# SQL query from time_in column but not from time_out column

Tags: mysql

I'm using mysql. I have a table time_record. There are four columns namely id, time_in, time_out and students_id. I only want to query the record of the latest time_in of the student but if the latest record of the student is in time_out, it will not query. How do I query the student's latest time_in record if given that the student still does not times out?

Thanks

Here is my sample code (though it returns both records from timein and timeout)

```
select concat (
        st.student_fname,
        ' ',
        st.student_lname
        ) as 'Name',
    t.students_id,
    t.time_in,
    t.time_out,
    case 
        when t.time_in > t.time_out
            then t.time_in
        else t.time_out
        end as MostRecentDate
from classes c
join student_classes s on c.id = s.classes_id
join timerecords t on t.students_id = s.students_id
join students st on s.students_id = st.student_id
where c.employees_id = 'sessionvalue2'
    and
where date (t.time_in) between date (now()) and date (now())
```

Comment: Post sample data, expected result and what you tried but didnt work.

Comment: Sorry, other columns are from other tables of my database. Date (t.time_in) between date (now()) and date (now()) allows quering of date within current daye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to query all results in which time_in is the latest entry and exclude results where time_out is the latest entry.

Try this:

SELECT DISTINCT(tr.id), tr.time_in
FROM time_record tr
WHERE tr.time_in > tr.time_out
ORDER BY tr.time_in DESC

Comment: It returns empty result though mu table has some records in it.

Comment: Oh my god thanks man. I've tried it again. I put the DISTINCT tr.id before the CONCAT and it now works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your time_out columns may have nulls due to which the comparison results in false in that case and it return time_out.

Also,

```
date (t.time_in) between date (now()) and date (now())
```

doesn't make any sense. If you want to check the time_in for today's date, do:

```
date(t.time_in) = curdate();
```

Use `curdate()` instead of `date(now())`.

or [Sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) so that index can be used if any:

```
date >= curdate()
and date < date_add(curdate(), interval 1 day)
```

Try flipping the condition like this:

```
select concat (
        st.student_fname,
        ' ',
        st.student_lname
        ) as 'Name',
    t.students_id,
    t.time_in,
    t.time_out,
    case 
        when t.time_in < t.time_out
            then t.time_out
        else t.time_in
        end as MostRecentDate
from classes c
join student_classes s on c.id = s.classes_id
join timerecords t on t.students_id = s.students_id
join students st on s.students_id = st.student_id
where c.employees_id = 'sessionvalue2'
and date >= curdate()
and date < date_add(curdate(), interval 1 day)
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I removed the columns' nulls and ot it queries now. But it still doesn't answer my question :(

Comment: @Jay please post sample data and expected output in the question